# Flex grid issue nesting multiple flex direction combinations

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the code below:

1. The `container` has two `div` children. I want the div children to be one below another;
2. For the first `div`, I want the `LinkT1` section, the `red button` and the `input`, to appear one after another from left to right, and the space between them to be split.
3. For the second `div`, I want the `LinkR1` section, the `LinkR2` sec, to be on the same row, one on the left and one on the right and the space between them to be split.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.75rem auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 40rem;
   border: 1px solid red;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div {
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }

.nav {
   color: blue;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: flex-start;
}


.items > * { 
    margin-right: 0.75rem; // to be defined as variable
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.items:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 
  
 

.button { 
background: red;
border-radius: .1875rem;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
letter-spacing: .0625rem;
padding: .375rem .75rem;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <a class="button" href="/accounts/register/">Lorem </a>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="input" />
            </form>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a few things :

- Your `container > div` class also needs to have the `display: flex;` property.
- It's your `item` section that needs to have `flex-direction: column;`, not your `nav` sections.
- Your second `nav` needs (according to your message) different rules than your first `nav`. So I separated them into different classes. I also added a rule stating that your second `nav` section has `width: 100%` so that the sections inside it are properly pushed on the sides.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.75rem auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 40rem;
   border: 1px solid red;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }

.nav {
   color: blue;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-row {
   color: blue;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
}

.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.items > * { 
    margin-right: 0.75rem; // to be defined as variable
    text-decoration: none;
 }

.items:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
 
.button { 
    background: red;
    border-radius: .1875rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: .0625rem;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
                <a href="">Link T1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
                <a href="">Link T2</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <a class="button" href="/accounts/register/">Lorem </a>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="input" />
            </form>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div>
        <div class="nav-row">
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
                <a href="">Link R1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
                <a href="">Link R2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```